# What is the conventional way of estimating a population parameter?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, confidence-interval, estimation

I was wondering about the correct way to approach the following question (I am quoting the question as it was originally written):

> Consider a particle residing at x = 1, y = 1 and the particle begins moving randomly (Brownian
> Motion). You are expected to conduct simulations to calculate the probability of x < 0 when
> the particle’s first intersection with X axis occurs (P(x < 0|y = 0 for the first time)). Please
> discuss about distribution of P(X< T| y=0 for the first time) for any T?

To calculate the mentioned probability, is it better to make many replications and take the average of them once (i.e. draw one sample with a large sample size) or draw many samples with a small sample size. E.g. one sample with n=1000, or 100 samples with n=10, or are they equivalent. Also, conventionally, is a confidence interval expected to be provided with the estimate?

Secondly, I could fit a t-distribution for the last part of the question, but I am not sure why it is t and not normal. It would be great if someone could comment on that.
I probably couldn't explain my quesiton well. So, sorry for that in advance.

TLDR, how would you solve the quoted question?

Comment: First, what are the distributions of moves in the $x$ and $y$ directions? Are they independent? (Maybe this is assumed to be bivariate normal with zero correlation if nothing else is specified.) Second, why do you want to fit $t$? Third, please add the self-study tag, read its wiki, and include any work your done.

Comment: The question does not involve estimating any parameters whatsoever. You are being asked to simulate a stochastic process many times and count the proportion of such paths that satisfy the condition. Each path must be simulated until it crosses the x axis the first time. The $T$ in the last part has nothing to do with Student's t, it is just a variable.